# how can i add an incrementing id to the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

i have four values filedata,filename,username,filestatus fetched from database but their is no id in the database,and i cant change the database,but need to add the id to jsp page

```
for(id=1;id<=20;id++){
System.out.println(id);
}

 %>
<tr>
<td><%=id %></td>
<td><%=filedate%></td>
<td><%=filename%></td>
<td><%=username%></td>
<td><%=filestatus%></td>
</tr>
<%
}
}
catch(SQLException ex){
System.out.println("exception--"+ex);

}
```

this is my code i tried giving an for loop but does not work

Comment: What is an ID for you if no ID exists in the db?

Comment: "can't change the database" ... so, why do you want to show a non-existing id? anyway, don't keep java code in your jsp file. use servlets

Comment: Awful code.  Scriptlets should never be used in JSPs.  Learn JSTL and add a loop index to that table; let it be your ID.

Comment: can you create the table **without** the id (jstl or scriptlet)? Once you have that loop, adding a constructed ID is quite simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should not put your own loop , instead u might have upper loop for result set / collection object for db records. So , increment a variable within loop and use that variable as a ID. If you are doing POC just do it in Scriptlet

```
<% int id = 1 ; %>
<% for(Files file : files) { %>

  <tr>
    <td><%=id %></td>
    <td><%=file.filedate%></td>
    <td><%=file.filename%></td>
    <td><%=file.username%></td>
    <td><%=file.filestatus%></td>
  </tr>
<% 
id++;
} %>
```